# Enter "-" into my textbox I get System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem when I enter "-" in my textbox I get an error. Can some one tell me where I went wrong on this code block?

```
Private Sub HourBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HourBox.TextChanged
    Label10.Text = CStr(Val(CostBox.Text) * Val(AppBox.Text) * Val(HourBox.Text))
    If HourBox.Text >= 24 Then
        Label2.Visible = True
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        HourBox.Text = "0"
        Label2.Text = "Hours must be between 0 - 24." & vbNewLine & "Select your appliance and try again."
    ElseIf HourBox.Text < 0 Then
        Label2.Visible = True
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        HourBox.Text = "0"
        Label2.Text = "Hours must be between 0 - 24." & vbNewLine & "Select your appliance and try again."
    End If
```

Comment: Put a break point to `Label10.Text = CStr(...)` and step through where went wrong. On a side note, you should convert the HourBox.Text before comparing.

Comment: dont try to validate every key stroke.  wait until the user says they are done

Comment: don't use textchanged

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if `HourBox` is a numeric value because if you want to enter -10, the event will fire on the -, then again on -1 and lastly on -10:

```
Private Sub HourBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HourBox.TextChanged
If IsNumeric(HourBox.Text) Then
    Label10.Text = CStr(Val(CostBox.Text) * Val(AppBox.Text) * Val(HourBox.Text))
    If HourBox.Text >= 24 Then
        Label2.Visible = True
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        HourBox.Text = "0"
        Label2.Text = "Hours must be between 0 - 24." & vbNewLine & "Select your appliance and try again."
    ElseIf HourBox.Text < 0 Then
        Label2.Visible = True
        Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        HourBox.Text = "0"
        Label2.Text = "Hours must be between 0 - 24." & vbNewLine & "Select your appliance and try again."
    End If
End If
```